# ГербОвый или гЕрбовый?

Tags: ударение

Добрый день! Расскажите, пожалуйста, про ударение в прилагательном "гербовый"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

герб - гЕрбовый, гЕрбового, гЕрбовому, гЕрбовым, о гЕрбовом.

Comment: спасибо большое!